# How do I put an image above a linked button using html?

Tags: html, image, button

So here I have a check out button and an image that shows up to the left of that button... How can I get the Image above the button?

```
<a href="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2&cl=282297&i=1381026" target="ej_ejc" class="ec_ejc_thkbx" onclick="return EJEJC_lc(this);">

<img src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/vi310-007a1757-ab94-4219-871c-fd4541c768dd-v2" alt="Faith Walker" style="height:200px;width:200px;">

<img src="https://www.e-junkie.com/ej/ej_add_to_cart.gif" border="0" alt="Add to Cart">
</a>
```

Comment: Put img tag above button and after img tag <br/>

Comment: can you provide more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an image button then use the following code:
`

```
<input type="image" src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/vi310-007a1757-ab94-4219-871c-fd4541c768dd-v2"/>
```

`

else if you just want the images above the button:
`

```
<img src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/vi310-007a1757-ab94-4219-871c-fd4541c768dd-v2" alt="Faith Walker" style="height:200px;width:200px;">
<br>
<img src="https://www.e-junkie.com/ej/ej_add_to_cart.gif" border="0" alt="Add to Cart">
<br>
<a href="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2&cl=282297&i=1381026" target="ej_ejc" class="ec_ejc_thkbx" onclick="return EJEJC_lc(this);">
</a>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

you can use css z-index:99 or a higher number than your button to bring it above your button

Comment: I believe OP wants to change the float of the content, not the layering with z-index.

Comment: can you provide peace of code that you create and style your button

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to put the image before the button in the code and apply a `display: block;` with CSS to the image (either inline using `style=""` or in your stylesheet).